# How to format date in pug with momentjs

Tags: express, momentjs, pug

I need to get the date a comment was made from the database, there is no problem with that, the problem is that the date is obtained in a strange format for example 2021-12-11T18:37:57.000Z, and I would like that it be something more readable, like 2021-12-11 15:31:14.

I have the pug file like this:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css")
        title Valoraciones
        script(src="https://momentjs.com/lib/moment/moment.min.js")
    body
        div.color-fondo
            h2.encabezado
                img(src="charla.png", alt="charla").img-tamano
                span Valoraciones
            div.center
                h3.titulo-centro 
                    img(src="bueno.png", alt="bueno").img-tamano
                    span ¡Gracias por brindarnos tu valoración!
            div.fondo-comentario
                div.estilo-comentario 
                    for item in data
                        div= item.comentario
                        div= item.fecha
                        div= item.username 
                        br
```

I have the app.js file like this

```
const express = require ('express');
const res = require('express/lib/response');
var rootRouter = require('./routes');
const comentarios = require('./controllers/ComentariosController');
const axios = require('axios');
var moment = require('moment'); // require
moment().format(); 

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', rootRouter);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    let data;
    axios.get('http://192.168.100.3:3000/api/comentarios')
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            data = response.data.data;
            console.log(data);
            res.render('index',{data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

[sample of how it looks in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E49z.png)

Answer (score 0):

use moment's formatting capability

```
fecha = moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
```

Comment: I tried adding it like this div= item.fecha = moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") and I get this error: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined, on the same line, I don't know if I'm adding it wrong or am I missing something else

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the moment library correctly?

Comment: Another thing to try is to convert the data before you render the page.  So just before you call res.render('index',{data}) in app.js,  set the date: date.feche = moment().format('YYYY_MM-DD")